# Convert a video to mp3 in python without ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have some problems when I tryed to convert a video to music in python with moviepy and the prompt given me a error, because this library need [ffmepg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows), so I can't install [ffmepg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows), because now only have the x64 version to download, and now I have this problem, and I thinking what is the other way to install the [ffmepg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) or convert a video to music! Can someone help-me, Thanks!

Code to convert:

```
with VideoFileClip(mp4f) as vc:
    with vc.audio as ac:
        ac.write_audiofile(mp3f)
```

Error:

```
OSError: MoviePy error: the file X could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

System details:
Python - 3.8.6
Windows 10 Pro x86

Comment: That just looks like a file not found error?

Comment: That's the problem the file exist but the moviepy can't see

Comment: I try this post from moviepy github https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/830